# Randomize a number of samples in a dataset specific to an experimetn's a participant number

Tags: python, pandas, coding-efficiency

I have a training dataset that is composed numpy array of examples `X_train`, and pandas dataframe labels `Y_train`. The dataframe contains three columns: The number of the class, the name of the class, and the participant in the experiment from which the example was measured. I want to randomize 3 participants, and extract a single example from each of them for a specific class. So far, I have managed to extract the indices, though I am sure my way is unnecessarily complicated.

```
Activities = ['eating'] * 60
Activities.extend(['sleeping'] * 60)
participants = np.repeat(np.arange(30)+1, 4).tolist()
Y_train = pd.DataFrame({'Activity_Name':Activities ,'partisipant': participants})

def plot_for_activity(act):
  # A sub dataframe with the intended activity
  sub_df = Y_train[Y_train['Activity_Name']==act]
  # Find indices of 3 different participents:
  Num_of_participents = sub_df['partisipant'].nunique()
  Ids = np.random.choice(sub_df['partisipant'].unique(), 3,replace=False)
  idx = list()
  for id in Ids:
    idx.extend(sub_df.loc[sub_df['partisipant']==id].sample(n=1).index.tolist())

  return idx

print(plot_for_activity('eating'))
print(plot_for_activity('sleeping'))
```

For example, I have data from 30 participants about sleeping and eating. Eventually, I want to present the data for sleeping, from two different random participants and the data from eating from two different random participants. The function should accept the activity name, and based on that, extract the data from two different random participants.

Can anyone offer a code that is more compact and clean for this?

Comment: So for each class, participant pair you want to extract a single sample? is that it? could you add some sample data (or something with the same structure) to better reason about your problem?

Comment: Sure, added. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes is better, but if you could add a sample of the dataframe it is even better

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Prose only gets you so far

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `sample` to get an one-line function:

```
def plot_for_activity(act):
    return Y_train.loc[Y_train['Activity_Name'].eq(act)] \
                  .groupby('partisipant').sample(1) \
                  .sample(3).index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> plot_for_activity('eating')
[16, 48, 8]

>>> plot_for_activity('sleeping')
[84, 100, 108]
```

Comment: With respect to my edits, did you mean something like `sub_df.groupby('Activity_Name')['partisipant'].sample(n=1)`? Because It does not yields me the same results.

Comment: As suggested by @MadPhysicist, provide a MRE. Without a consistent sample of `Y_train` (and the expected output), it's difficult to help you much.

Comment: I have already added an example data, an explanation of the output I am looking for, and an example function that produces such output. I can't see a way to be more specific as the requested output is random. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Does it what you expect?

Comment: Yes. it produces my expected output.